# Unity3d memory management

Tags: unity

I am baking animation to draw a huge amount of crowd in unity3d. I am storing mesh of each frame of skinned mesh in the list and just iterating over it. I can't use the compute shader as I want to target low-end devices too. But now I am facing memory issues as mesh consumes over 1.5gb of memory. Is there any way I can free memory consumes by mesh?

Comment: Have you looked at [gpu instancing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html) ?

Comment: I am already using gpu instancing